# Why did my autogenerated avatar change?

Tags: bug

Recently icons in stackexhange network had a bout of confusion. Then some people reported that the icons of users were all wrong. Now icons seem to have stabilized to a new normal. Unfortunately my icon has changed.

Did the algorithm determining the gravatar change? How do i get the old one back? Do I really need to submit a synthetic image that mimics the previous one? Is this a bug?

Comment: Migrated to Meta since this isn't specific to us or something we'd be able to help you with